# Multiple forms and one submit in django. Errors on the form that is not submitted

Tags: django, django-forms

I am able to successfully update any of the three forms. However, my problem is that if the change password form is empty it throws errors on it (like passwords too short, incorrect current password etc), unlike the other forms where I don't get errors if I leave them unchanged. How can I approach the fix? I tried setting `request.POST or None` to no avail and I am running out of ideas. I also don't use `{{ form.as_p }}`, but rather go field by field. Could that be an issue?

The form

`forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'first_name',
                'placeholder': 'First Name'}),

            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'last_name',
                'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),

            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'email',
                'placeholder': 'Email'}),

        }


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mobile',)

        widgets = {
            'mobile': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'mobile',
                'placeholder': 'Phone Number'})
        }


class MyPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):

    old_password = forms.CharField(
        label=("Old password"),
        required=False,
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'new_password2',
                'type': 'password',
                'placeholder': 'Old Password'}),
    )

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=("New password"),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'new_password2',
                'type': 'password',
                'placeholder': 'Enter new Password'}),
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=("New password confirmation"),
        required=False,
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'lnd-user__input',
                'id': 'new_password2',
                'type': 'password',
                'placeholder': 'Repeat new Password'}),
    )
```

`views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def user_settings(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
        password_change_form = MyPasswordChangeForm(user)
        context = {
            'uform': user_form,
            'pform': user_profile_form,
            'pwdform': password_change_form,
            'user': user}

        return render(request, 'accounts/user_settings.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

        user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
        user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_profile)
        password_change_form = MyPasswordChangeForm(user, request.POST or None, use_required_attribute=False)
        print password_change_form.is_valid(), password_change_form.error_messages
        if request.POST:
            if user_form.is_valid() is True and user_profile_form.is_valid() is True:
                user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                user.save()
                profile = user_profile_form.save(commit=False)
                user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                profile.user = user
                profile.save()

            if password_change_form.is_valid() is True:
                user_pwd_form = password_change_form.save()
                update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
                user_pwd_form.save()

            context = {
                'uform': user_form,
                'pform': user_profile_form,
                'pwdform': password_change_form,
                'user': user,
            }

            return render(request, 'accounts/user_settings.html', context)
```

Comment: It looks like that form is not mandatory, so you should check if that form has any data in it and then validate it. Or use some other way to identify if data in that form is also submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't want the password form to fail validation unless SOME of the fields are filled in but not all of them.  Whereas by making the fields required django will fail validation if any are left blank.  So what you should do is to make the all the form fields `required=False`, then add a `clean` method to your password form, something like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    data = super(MyPasswordChangeForm, self).clean()

    # if django field validation already failed, don't do any more validation
    # because the field values we need to check might not be present.
    if self.errors:
        return data

    # you could do this a lot of different ways, some of them simpler probably...
    fields = ('old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2')
    for fn in fields:
        # if any field contains data
        if data[fn]:
            for fn in fields:
                # if any field does not contain data
                if not data[fn]:
                    raise ValidationError("All fields must be filled in.")
            break
    return data
```

This way, if the user does not fill in any fields on the changepassword form, it won't fail validation.  Then, if you want to see whether the person actually wants to change their password, you'll have to do something in your view like:

```
if form.cleaned_data['new_password1']:
    # put code here to change the users password
```

Note that I did not test this code so it might not be perfect but it should be fairly close to what you need.

In Django forms, the `clean` method is the hook that they provide for you to do form validation that involves more than one field.. for example, if two number inputs have to add up to a third number, that's where you would check that.  If there's any problem with the form input, raise a `ValidationError` exception and Django will display the validation error on the form.